# Interop Redemption library crashing on release but not on debug version outlook add-in

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-redemption

I'm using Interop.Redemption 5.7 in my outlook add-in (plug-in) but when i build the app in release and start the outlook plugin i get stack trace for some reason and when i build the same app for debug no any error add-in works fine.

This is only on Win7 FR with office on FR language. When i use EN versions everything works fine.

Stack trace:

> Impossible de charger le fichier ou l'assembly 'Interop.Redemption,
>   Version=5.7.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=----' ou
>   une de ses dépendances.

Google translate:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Interop.Redemption, Version =
>   5.7.0.0, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = -----' or one of its dependencies.

What can be different between debug and release build?

Comment: do you deploy Redemption64.dll in the app directory ? That's work fine for me, in version 5.5 (Win and Office FR)

Comment: I add them to the root of the project but i don't reference them, i have installed redemption as COM component and then added as reference to the project.

Comment: In my projet, `Interop.Redemption` is referenced, and I have a post-build action `copy $(SolutionDir)External\Redemption.dll $(TargetDir)Redemption.dll`

Comment: Do you reference the library that you include your-self in the project or COM component? if you used copied libraries did you used x64 or x32 because i should run the app on both platforms versions x32/x64.

Comment: Redemption is referenced in a COM Component. Then both x32 and x64 is copied (both can be loaded by COM). Take a look to that example : http://forum.winbatch.com/index.php?PHPSESSID=t8j8f2nmo03dm7k8rjet2sf0u1&topic=1060.msg4949#msg4949

Comment: Can't get it working, no idea what's going on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick was the dll was not deployed to the target directory for some reason... I didn't add them from COM component, just added in the project and reference from there.